# Why does my UITextField always return the last value in my array?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";


NSMutableArray *fields=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

MDSpreadViewCell *cell = [aSpreadView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[MDSpreadViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:MDSpreadViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

        for (i =0; i < N; i++){
        NSLog (@"tag = %i", i);

        [fields  addObject:[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 185, 30)]];
        [[fields objectAtIndex:i] setTag:i];

        NSString *John =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];

             [[fields objectAtIndex:i] setText:John];

      [[fields objectAtIndex:i] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [[fields objectAtIndex:i] setDelegate:self];
        [[fields objectAtIndex:i] setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
           viewWithTag:i]).text;
            [cell addSubview:[fields objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    return cell;
```

What is output to the console is correct: Tag = 0, 1, 2, 3, etc., but every cell just says the last value in the array.  I've tried putting the for statement in different locations as well as returning the cell in different blocks.  I am sure it is something simple that I am overlooking.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish in this code?  You are adding multiple UITextFields to each cell, but the frame size & location of the fields is always the same, so only the top field in each cell will be seen.

Comment: I wanted to add 1 textfield for every cell and then I want to save all the user inputs in those cells.  Think of a traditional spreadsheet.

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code.  I'm assuming the snippet above is from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` ?  If you only want one text field per cell you shouldn't be using a for loop.

Comment: Yes, that's similar to what I am working from, but my Method is custom and called: - (MDSpreadViewCell *)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)rowPath forColumnAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)columnPath                     When I don't use the for loop, I just get i = 0 for both console output and for my cells.

Comment: please clean up your code.  this code can't even compile.  you have this snippet `viewWithTag:i]).text` all by itself.  we want to help you, but when you paste in code that isn't even valid, and don't bother to format it to be readable, either, it's a little difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may only be a partially useful answer, since you have some other issues to consider that I don't see addressed in the code snippet you've shown so far (most notably, that you'll need some sort of Model, such as a multidimentional array, that holds the spreadsheet data independently of the table view, and also code that will update the Model when the user changes any of the values in the text fields.)

But I think at this point you are just trying to create textfields in your table cells and get some numbers to appear in them.  You might try something like this:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
MDSpreadViewCell *cell = [aSpreadView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[MDSpreadViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:MDSpreadViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 185, 30)]];

    textField.tag = 1;
    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [textField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [cell addSubview:textField];
}

UITextField *textFieldForCell = [cell viewWithTag:1];
int numberInCell = rowPath.row + columPath.column;
textFieldForCell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", numberInCell];

return cell;
```

Just as a future note, it would have been helpful in your original question to indicate that you are using [MDSpreadView](https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView/tree/master/Classes)

Comment: Jon clarification question-- How do I access the textField contents in a different method?  NSString *text = ((UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1]).text;
    NSLog (@"Element 1 = %@", text);
Works great, but any tag other than 1 is "Null".  If tag is a constant, then why is it used here?

Comment: The short answer to your clarification question is that "you don't".  The textfields are just to display the contents of your app's Model (see the 1st paragraph of my answer).  If you need to access you Model's data from other methods, you should access the model directly.  Aside from being a good MVC practice, this is important because once your cells scroll off the screen they can be reused for other parts of your table, so can't rely on the values in them.  Setting the tag value to 1 is just a convenience so that you can easily reference the textfield from within the cell.